# Why is this website using 1024px as a base for its percentage-based layout?

Tags: css

I'm following a tutorial to build responsive websites (for mobile devices).
The widths of a [sample website](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-flexible.html) in the tutorial are defined as percentages:

(**CSS**)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
.section:after,
ul.nav:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ */
/* v1.0 | 20080212 */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td { margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent; }
body { line-height:1; }
ol,ul { list-style:none; }
blockquote,q { quotes:none; }
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after { content:'';content:none; }
ins { text-decoration:none; }
del { text-decoration:line-through; }
table { border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0; }

body {
    background: #E4E4E4 url("site/bg.png");
    color: #292929;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.82);
    font: normal 100% Cambria, Georgia, serif;
    -moz-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
a {
    color: #890101;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s color linear;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s color linear;
    transition: 0.2s color linear;
}
a:hover {
    color: #DF3030;
}
#page {
    background: url("site/rag.png") repeat-x;
    padding: 2em 0;
}
.inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 93.75%;      /* 960px / 1024px */
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.amp {
    font-family: Baskerville, Garamond, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Hoefler Text", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.mast {
    float: left;
    width: 31.875%; /* 306px / 960px */
}
h1 {
    background: url("site/logo-bg.png") no-repeat 50% 0;
}
h1 a {
    padding-top: 117px;
    height: 162px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.intro,
.main,
.footer {
    float: right;
    width: 65.9375%;    /* 633px / 960px */
}
.intro {
    margin-top: 117px;
}
.intro div {
    line-height: 1.4;
}
ul.nav {
    border-top: 1px solid #888583;
    margin: 2em auto 0;
    width: 64.379%;
}
ul.nav a {
    background: url("site/ornament.png") no-repeat 0 100%;
    font: bold 14px/1.2 "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Georgia, serif;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding: 1em 0.5em 3em;
    margin-bottom: -1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
    background-position: 50% 100%;
}
li.first a {
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF9EF;
    padding-top: 1.25em;
}
ul.nav i {
    font: normal 10px Baskerville, Garamond, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Hoefler Text", "Times New Roman", serif;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.intro h2 {
    font: normal 2em "Hoefler Text", "Baskerville old face", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}
.main h2 {
    background: url("site/ornament.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.75em 0 1em;
}
.main h2 b {
    background: url("site/bg.png");
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
.figure {
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: 0 3.317535545023696682% 1.5em 0;            /* 21px / 633px */
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 31.121642969984202211%;              /* 197px / 633px */
}
.figure b {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Georgia, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.figure img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 1em;
}
li#f-mycroft,
li#f-winter {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.footer {
    background: url("site/ornament.png") 50% 0 repeat-x;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0 20px;
}
.footer p {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
</style>

</head>
```

I have no idea why the author of that tutorial chose 1024px as base for its percentage-based layout.

What could be the reason?

(I'm a bit puzzled because the comments say 960px, so I assume the author wanted the layout to have a 960px of max-width, but in my browser it displays 1148.43px).

Comment: could it be because it's a standard screen resolution?

Comment: hi can i ask what it means in the comments when it says: width: 93.75%;      /* 960px / 1024px */?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Tablets resolution have  `"1024px"`.

Ex: Ipad-- portrait view.

Answer (score 0):

The ipad has a 1024px height screen, might have been testing/targeting that.

Comment: Depends on how you hold it... :)